# cocos2d-x 3.0 rc0 : develop for android in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm on windows xp & Eclipse Kepler. I want to develop with cocos2d-x, but I have some problem.

First, I created project.

```
cocos new MyGame -p com.myprog.MyGame -l cpp -d MyGame
```

and I tried run:

```
cd MyGame
cocos run -s MyGame -p android
```

and it succeeded.

The problem happens when I open it by eclipse. I create eclipse project, `Android Project From Existing Code`.

[image]

[image]

But I can't know what to do next.. even I don't know how to build! (`Project - Build` doesn't work..)

Moreover, `Classes`, `cocos2dx`, `extensions` and `scripting` folder are broken..

I tried to find solution, but people are saying about only cocos2d-x 2.x ...

Even if `README.md` seems to say about 2.x!

Could anyone tell me how do I do?

Comment: Broken folders are the virtual folders and you can go to properties and edit there path. To build project you just need to select project and click on run or goto `Project -> Build Project` option.

Answer (score 1):

Installation Process:

Cocos2d require [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html)

First install NDK ->

This links may help you :

http://nikhilvithlani.blogspot.in/2013/07/install-android-ndk-for-windows_6.html

Cocos 2d installation link:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_set_up_the_android_cocos2d-x_development_environment_on_Windows_7

Download cocos 2d version and follow the instruction in above link

This packages you required in cygwin: search and install:

```
autoconf, automake, binutils, gcc-core, gcc-g**, gcc4-core, gcc4-g**, gdb, pcre, pcre-devel, gawk, make
```

After installation cygwin,ndk and you need to config in C/C++ preference in eclipse(Don't forget to install c/c++ plugin in eclipse)

[image]

My NDK and PATH is :

> NDK_ROOT->C:/android-ndk-r9c
>
> PATH->C:\android-ndk-r9c;C:\Cygwin\bin;

Then import the sample project :

> cocos2d-x-2.2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android

Import the library :

> cocos2d-x-2.2.2\cocos2dx\platform\android\java

[image]

Add the library to hello world project

when you import hello world project eclipse automatically include the header files:

> bash F:/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh 
>   cygwin warning:
>     MS-DOS style path detected: F:\cocos2d-x-2.2.2\samples\Cpp\HelloCpp\proj.android
>     Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android
>     CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
>     Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
>       http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
>   NDK_ROOT = C:/android-ndk-r9c
>   COCOS2DX_ROOT = /cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..
>   APP_ROOT = /cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/..
>   APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android
>   Using prebuilt externals
>   + C:/android-ndk-r9c/ndk-build -C /cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android NDK_MODULE_PATH=/cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../..:/cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
>   make: Entering directory '/cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android'
>   Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-9 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
>   Android NDK: WARNING:/cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/../../../../cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries
>   [armeabi] Install        : libhellocpp.so => libs/armeabi/libhellocpp.so
>   make: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/f/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android'

After get output in console right click project and goto properties and choose paths and symbols under c/c++ general

[image]

Run the project and you can see the output :

[image]

Useful links:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2itbQceTQGI

Comment: CYGWIN is no more used in cocos2dx projects and you can use python or directly use `ndk-build.cmd` to build project on Windows.

Comment: I'M SAYING ABOUT COCOS2DX-3.0 RC0. not 2.x

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in different way though you are on windows you have to use [Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673) its free and also it will give you good IntelliSense support.
Every time you edit using MS VS2012 run **proj.android/build_native.py** and then you can run your app from eclipse as usual.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't support debugging on android ... I want to use eclipse.